# amplify api, Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'listNoteDatas' in type 'Query' is undefined @ 'listNoteDatas''

Tags: kotlin, aws-amplify

** It's written using a program of translator. **

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-android-app-amplify/module-four/?nc1=h_ls

I coded as above.

In the case of create, it was performed normally, and it was possible to check the data in DynamoDB in the AWS account.
However, in the case of read, an error message of "Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'listNoteDatas' in type 'Query' is undefined @ 'listNoteDatas'' is returned.

```
Amplify.API.query(
            ModelQuery.list(NoteData::class.java),
            { response ->
                Log.i(TAG, "Queried 1")

                for (noteData in response.data) {
                        Log.i(TAG, noteData.name)
                        UserData.addNote(UserData.Note.from(noteData))
                    }
            },
            { error -> Log.e(TAG, "Query failure", error) }
        )
```

By designating the id with the get function instead of the list, it was performed normally when reading.

```
Amplify.API.query(
            ModelQuery.get(NoteData::class.java, "id value checked in DynamoDB"),
            { response ->
                Log.i(TAG, "Queried 2")

                if (response.data != null){
                    UserData.addNote(UserData.Note.from(response.data))
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "response.data != null")
                }
            },
            { error -> Log.e(TAG, "Query failure", error) }
        )
```

How to run ModelQuery.list normally?

** It's written using a program of translator. **

Comment: In the schema edit of AWS AppSync, we have verified that there is no undefined error when changing the name of query defined as listNoteData to listNoteDatas.

However, the data that inquired DynamoDB with ModelQuery.list still does not come out.

Answer (score 1):

1. first you need to change schema

In AWS AppSync > Yours > Schema

find `type Query {...}` in left side and change
`listNoteData(filter...) to listNoteDatas`(filter...)

click save schema button on top right

[image]

2. setting resolver at listNoteDatas

scroll down find `Query section in Resolvers` in right side

click connect `button on listNoteDatas`, select `NoteDataTable` for resolver table, in Configure mapping templates in order select `List items` for first, select `Return single item` for second

and save resolver

[image]

3. build run, no error

[image]

Good!

Answer (score 0):

Edit scheme to change to listNoteDatas and connect to DB.NoteData table to work normally.